# If a matrix A is symmetric, and J is the matrix where the columns of J are the orthonormal eigenbasis of A, are the rows of J also orthonormal?

Tags: linear-algebra

I think so because A is symmetric, so A^T causes the orthornormal eigenbasis to be J^T, so the rows of J are also an orthonormal?

Answer (score 4):

In general, if a square matrix $J$ has orthonormal columns, then $J^\top J = I$ and thus $J^\top = J^{-1}$. This implies $JJ^\top = I$ as well, which is equivalent to the rows of $J$ being orthonormal.